# Intellij add standard attributes to html tag via plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

In IntelliJ,

when I type `<in` it auto suggests me the `<input>` -field. If I press tab/enter, I get what was proposed.
I am coming from atom for frontend stuff, where if you press enter there,
you get the `input` field with the basic attributes, like this:

```
<input type="" name="" value="">
```

Is there a plugin / setting for intellij to do the same?
I am already using live template/edit, this does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Use this a workaround `<input type="$SELECTION$" name="$SELECTION$" value="$SELECTION$">`

Comment: So i need to create my own template for each frequently used html tag? There is no plugin for that? I sure am not the first to encounter this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enter the opening angle bracket, just enter `in`, hit `Ctrl+Space`, then choose `input` *Emmet* live template from completion list. By default, it will expand to `<input type="text">`, but you can change the `input` live template in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, Zen HTML** to add more predefined attributes to it, like:

```
<input type="$VAR0$" name="$NAME$" value="$VALUE$">
```

Comment: ctrl+space was new to me, only knew alt+enter. thanks!